# Arcpy doesn't put shapefiles in another database despite being defined

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap

I'm trying to calculate the meancenter of a pharmacies in Istanbul file by grouping with the case field "ilce_adi" which means neighbourhood's name. It works well but despite being defined, it does not put the output shapefiles into a new geographic database. Here is my script.

```
import arcpy
import time
 

input_FC = r"C:\ScriptData\data.gdb\pharmacies"
CF_output = "pharmacies_CENTRALFEATURE.shp"
MEAN_output = "pharmacies_MEANCENTER.shp"

CASE_Field = "ilce_adi"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\ScriptData\process.gdb"



print"The script is working.."

start_time = time.time()

             
arcpy.CentralFeature_stats(input_FC, CF_output, "Euclidean Distance", "#","#",CASE_Field)

arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(input_FC, MEAN_output, "#",CASE_Field,"#")

end_time = time.time()
process_time = end_time - start_time

print "Script is done in {:.2f} seconds".format(process_time)
```

Comment: Just be explicit and set the full output path for your tools?

Comment: Shapefile is a file-based format. It can't be placed in a database (at least, not usefully). It can be *converted* into a database table, which is what FeatureClassToFeatureClass does, but at that point it is no longer a shapefile. In fact, if you try to name a feature class with a ".shp" suffix, it fails with an invalid name. Please [Edit] the question to include the relevant geoprocessing logs and error message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not set the output path. A shapefiles are to be saved inside folder. Use the following as outputs

```
import os
input_dir = r"C:\ScriptData"
CF_output =os.path.join(input_dir, "pharmacies_CENTRALFEATURE.shp")
MEAN_output = os.path.join(input_dir,"pharmacies_MEANCENTER.shp")
```

the outputs will be saved here:

```
'C:\\ScriptData\\pharmacies_CENTRALFEATURE.shp'
'C:\\ScriptData\\pharmacies_MEANCENTER.shp'
```